# PHPMailer - Anexo não tem extensão

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, phpmailer

Boas, ao enviar o meu anexo usando PHPMailer, se não adicionar uma extensão após a variável, não consigo obter a extensão do ficheiro seleccionado ou seja:

`$mail->addAttachment($uploadfile)` deveria de enviar o ficheiro, dando o seu nome e tipo, porém envia apenas o nome temporário do mesmo, que para mim não há problema, mas visto não ter extensão o ficheiro chega sempre como algo nâo legível ao destinatário, porém se usar algo deste género:

`$mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'exemplo.jpg')`, o envio é feito, o nome do ficheiro passa para "exemplo.jpg" e torna o ficheiro legível ao destinatário.

Alguem me sabe dizer qual o erro que eu estou a fazer? Já fui buscar a extensão via `$_FILES['userfile']['type']` e substitui pelo "exemplo.jpg" porém o que me retorna no email é "image/jpeg" o que não me define a extensão, continuando assim o ficheiro "vazio".

Atenção: Estou a usar codeigniter.

Este é o código do meu controlador:

```
if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {;

$uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['userfile']['name']));

     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            var_dump($uploadfile);

            $file_type = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

            $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile);

            if (!$mail->send()) {
                echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
                echo "Message sent!";
            }
    } else {
            echo 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
}
```

Isto é o que é retornado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pelo que entendi, vc está criando uma arquivo temp (`tempnam`) e esse arquivo tem extensão `.tmp`. Em vista, a manipulação dele está incorreta.

Answer (score 0):

`tempnam` — Cria um nome de arquivo único

`hash SHA-256` criptografa o nome do arquivo, portanto a extensão foi pro beleleu :)

Você pode optar por uma das soluções abaixo:

```
if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {

  $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['userfile']['name']));

  $arquivo = $_FILES["userfile"];

  $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']));
  $file_extension = end($ext);

  /***************** Nomes dos anexos ***************************/

  // Anexo com o nome original do arquivo                   
  //$mail->AddAttachment($arquivo['tmp_name'], $arquivo['name']  );

  // Anexo com o nome constituído pela variavel $uploadfile concatenado com a extensão original do arquivo
  $mail->AddAttachment($arquivo['tmp_name'], $uploadfile.".".$file_extension  );

 //anexo com novo nome e extensão original do arquivo
 //$mail->addAttachment($arquivo['tmp_name'], "NomeQualquer".".$file_extension);
```